# delete a row from a table that references an other table with tables created by JPA annotated entity classes

Tags: java, jpa, entity

I have generated my database tables from JPA annotated entity classes,like this:

```
@Entity
@Table (name="chauffeur")
public class Chauffeur{    

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "MYNOTIFSEQ") //identificateur de de la séquence
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "MYNOTIFSEQ", sequenceName = "MY_SEQ") //nom de la séquence dans la base
    private Long id; // Identifiant formation (Clé primaire)
    private String nom;
    private String prenom;
    private String adresse;
    private String telephone;
    private String login;
    private String motdepasse;
    private String position;
    private String disponible;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "c")
    private Taxi t;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "chau")
    private  Favoris favoris;
```

and this class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "favoris")
public class Favoris {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "MYNOTIFSEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "MYNOTIFSEQ", sequenceName = "MY_SEQ")
    private Long id; // Identifiant formation (Clé primaire)

    @OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE},orphanRemoval=true)
    private Taxi taxi;

    @OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE},orphanRemoval=true)
    private Chauffeur chau;
```

my problem is I want to delete a row from Chauffeur table,but this table references the table Favoris
that's why I have this error:

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-02292: integrity constraint (MYBASE.FK_SUIDVMBNQQO4MUFI27VCLVPMV) violated - child record found
```

this is the query that I have used:

```
delete from Chauffeur where id ='1'
```

how can I solve the problem and thanks

Comment: Delete the referenced row from Favoris first?

Comment: @Kilazur,you mean that I should apply the delete query in Favoris first then the Chauffeur table??

Comment: If your deletion doesn't work because of Favoris, it means you don't have a CASCADE for it, and in such case, yes you should delete the referenced Favoris' row first.

Comment: Kilazur,should I use @CascadeOnDelete annotation like this:

Comment: @OneToOne(mappedBy="owner", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={CascadeType.ALL}) @CascadeOnDelete private Chauffeur chau;

Comment: I sadly don't have much knowledge of the ORM you're using, so I can't tell the annotations, but I guess that's an idea.